# How do I create an index using a json in ElasticSearch NEST, c#.net

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

I used to create index from json using the following code,

```
var ESClient = new ElasticClient(setting);
ESClient.Raw.IndicesCreatePost("indexname", "strJson");
```

Now, that the nugetPackage of NEST elastic version has changed to 2.0.4, I am unable to work using the existing code.
Could anyone please let me know what could be replacement for it.

Thanks

Comment: `ElasticClient.Raw` has been renamed to `ElasticClient.LowLevel`.